# Regresar la palabra mas frecuente

Tags: java, array, lista, bucle-for

Retorna la palabra más frecuente en el arreglo palabras, que no se encuentre en el arreglo stopwords. Se asume que al menos un elemento de palabras no aparece en stopwords y el elemento más frecuente es único.

```java
    static String palabra_clave (String[] palabras, String[] stopwords) {
        for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++){
            
            for (int i = 0; i < stopwords.length; i++){
            }
    }
    System.out.println(palabra_clave(palabras, stopwords));
    }
```

Ejemplo: el siguiente fragmento de código debe imprimir dog:

```java
String[] palabras = {"dog", "cat", "bird", "dog", "cat", "the", "the", "cat", "the", "bird", "the", "the", "bear", "sheep", "dog", "bear", "dog");

String[] stopwords = ["from", "the", "bear"};

System.out.println(palabra_clave (palabras, stopwords));
```

Comment: ¿ Es obligatorio usar Array ? ¿ Puedes utilizar listas o elementos de java.util ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:**

Me gusto tu pregunta pero no pude resolverlo usando solamente arreglos, utilicé la clase java.util.Vector. Mi solución cree un objeto llamado ElementosVector para que cada elemento del vector tenga una palabra y un contador. También cree la función palabrasCorrectas (estas, palabras, stopwords); que esta función lo que hace es llenar el vector "estas" con las palabras correctas. Después es sencillo la lógica si son igual se suma uno al contador y si no se añade ese elemento al vector. Luego, se busca el contador mayor y se exprime la palabra que esta en el mismo indice que el contador. Aquí esta el código.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    
    static String palabra_clave (String[] palabras, String[] stopwords) {
        
        Vector<String> estas = new Vector<String>(); 
        Vector<ElementosVector> elementos = new Vector<ElementosVector>();
        String estaEs = "";
        int mayor = 0;
        Main.palabrasCorrectas(estas, palabras, stopwords);
        
        elementos.add(new ElementosVector(estas.get(0), 0));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < estas.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < elementos.size(); j++) {
                if(estas.get(i).equals(elementos.get(j).getPalabra())) {
                    int contador = elementos.get(j).getContador() + 1;
                    elementos.get(j).setContador(contador);
                } else {
                    elementos.add(new ElementosVector(estas.get(i), 1));
                }   
            }
        }
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < elementos.size(); i++) {
            if(elementos.get(i).getContador() > mayor) {
                mayor = elementos.get(i).getContador();
                estaEs = elementos.get(i).getPalabra();
            }
        }
        return estaEs;
    }

    private static void palabrasCorrectas(Vector<String> palabrasQueSon, String[] palabras, String[] stopwords) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Vector<String> palabrasQueSon2 = new Vector<String>();
        for(int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++) {
                palabrasQueSon2.add(stopwords[j]);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < palabras.length; j++) {
            palabrasQueSon.add(palabras[j]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < palabrasQueSon.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < palabrasQueSon2.size(); j++) {
                if(palabrasQueSon.get(i) == palabrasQueSon2.get(j)) {
                    palabrasQueSon.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] palabras = {"dog", "cat", "bird", "dog", "cat", "the", "the", "cat", "the", "bird", "the", "the", "bear", "sheep", "dog", "bear", "dog"};
        String[] stopwords = {"from", "the", "bear"};
        
        System.out.println(Main.palabra_clave(palabras, stopwords));
    }

}
```

**Observaciones:**

Algunos “the" no se me borran y realmente no sé porque.